# How to unset/overwrite the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable in terminal?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-speech

I'm having a need of using "Google speech API" for my application. For that, I had installed "Google cloud storage SDK". I followed this link 
"https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu" to install gcloud.

Then I had run this command "`set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS /path/to/google-speech-API-key/key.json`" on terminal to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. But when I try to test I got this exception
`"Error reading credential file from environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, value '/path/to/google-speech-API-key': File does not exist"`. I'm sure that the directory exists and it has all the permissions.

So then I ran this command `"gcloud auth application-default login"` to actually set the default key. I got the below warning

```
"The environment variable [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS] is set to:
  [/path/to/google-speech-API-key]
Credentials will still be generated to the default location:
  [/path/to/.config/gcloud/key.json]
To use these credentials, unset this environment variable before
running your application."
```

So, now how could I unset or overwrite the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Answer (score 6):

So if you follow Cloud Speech [authentication documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/auth#application_default_credentials) they suggest to do

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=PATH_TO_KEY_FILE
```

You can check the value and if file is readable by running following commands in your terminal

```
echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
cat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

Note that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is an environment variable which is set in your current shell session. If you start another terminal session (NOT via this one) that environment variable will not be set. Also you can unset it in this session via

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=
```

That said you probably should not use user credentials obtained via

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

as they are not tied to your project. Instead use service account key obtained from your project.

Comment: searched too much to get this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

UNIX:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=
```

[image]
Windows[image]

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=
```

More Information on [docs page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#unix)